# Installing NodeJS on GoDaddy Dedicated Server Causes any Issues?

Tags: node.js, apache, dedicated-server

We have a dedicated linux server on GoDaddy and have hosted a web application(PHP & MySQL) running on HTTPS.

We would like to install NodeJS on the same server.

Would like to know, Installing NodeJS on the same server breakdown the existing services or creates any issues?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly run LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP) side-by-side with Node.js on the same server. Apache can be configured to proxy requests to Node.js and vice versa. If you want to serve some pages through node.js you will have to put a proxy in front of Apache and node.js that routes the request between both. It won't create any problem as long as you run both of them parallaly and you don't want to replace each other. Here's the guide you can follow.

https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/01/run-nodejs-application-lamp-stack-server/